# non-production MySQL query/UDF that triggers a bash command

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, user-defined-functions, navicat

How can I make a MySQL query/script that will trigger a bash command and finish when it's done?

here is what I thought of:

1. make a bash daemon that will monitor a MySql table and execute command uppon change
2. use the bash script to update the table on finish and the MySQL script that modified the table sleep/loop  until it happens

Is this possible? or is there a better way?
I want to make this sql script so I can incorporate it in a Navicat MySQL-MSSQL Batch job

---

**update:** 
this is not a production or public server, I use it just for data filtering, so if I can introduce a UDF or alter the server to execute shell commands it's ok, as long as it can be triggered using the remote CLI.

Comment: Do you know of SSIS? Maybe this can also do what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've heard of it but I didn't find anything about running a linux script on a remote MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can execute shell commands with your mysql script with ! shell command. Or you can create a shell script that have mysql commands. Either could work for you.

Comment: "_execute shell commands with your mysql script with ! shell command_" ? please rephrase or give an example.
Also if I would have worked only on the Linux server, I wouldn't have asked but the query is executed remotely by the Navicat Batch Job (navicat is a windows MySql & MSSQL client)

Comment: Mysql shell escape character is !, you may have to use \!, which allows you to escape to shell within your mysql script. An example would be '\! ls' in unix and '\! dir' in windows.

Comment: unfortunately `system` OR `\!` doesn't work with the MySQL CLI, it only works with the cmd tool installed on the server.